# Which verb should be used with injection - give or inject? What is the better way to talk about the injection?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, verbs

Normally, in India people around me say

> — **Doctor will give you the injection**.

So, is **give the injection** fine or **inject the injection** would be better?

Or is there a better word for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely okay is "giving someone an injection". It's not just *India*, by the way.

[OALD entry:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/injection?q=injection)

> *'to **give** somebody an **injection'***

This use is very common and I've been practicing this for years.

My medical mind says that you can use *inject* but then, it is *far more common* when you have the name of the substance you are injecting. Say...

> Doctor *injected* **penicillin** into the muscle
>
> Mice were *injected* with some **chemicals**

[I'm a doctor from *India!*]

Answer (score 0):

While both "**give the injection**" and "**inject the injection**" are technically correct, for the sake of sentence flow and smoothness, we prefer "**give the injection**." The repetition just sounds strange to the ear there.

Another common option is **administer**, which is used almost exclusively with medical procedures (in this context, anyway):

> The doctor will now administer the injection.

It implies some sort of authority, care, or knowledge. You certainly wouldn't say that a drug user "administers" the drugs.

Answer (score 0):

Doctors *give* the injection and patients *take* the injection.

Often, you'll see this as *give the shot* and *take the shot*.